# Fetch Google Search results via Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension and I need to search a string in Google search engine and check if it appears among the first 10 results.

I have tried to use google search API but it didn't work, I used the following:

```
chrome.search.query({queryinfo:"search_string"});
```

And I get:

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
```

any ideas?

Comment: Just like most of extension APIs it needs to be listed in `permissions` and cannot be used in a content script. Also, it may be the wrong method because this API opens a new tab/window, whereas you may want to make a direct network request using the standard `fetch` in the background script, for example.

Answer (score 1):

you must use "text" and no "queryinfo"

```
chrome.search.query({text:"search_string"});
```

And you must used in manifest.json permission :

```
  "permissions": [
    "search"
  ]
```